# pointer to a struct inside of a struct from another file in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I need to create a program that will act like a stack.
I did all the function correctly.
The problem is that I have two structs in two files but when i'm trying to put a pointer to the other struct it won't let me.

The first struct is declared in the file "linkedList.h":

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H
#define _LINKEDLIST_H
#include "stack.h"

struct elements{
    int element;
    elements* pNext;
};
typedef struct elements elements;


void push(myStack *s, int element);  // insert element to top of the stack
int pop(myStack *s); //remove element from top of the stack

#endif
```

The second struct is declared in the second file "stack.h":

```
#ifndef _MYSTACK_H
#define _MYSTACK_H
#include "linkedList.h"

struct myStack{
    int maxSize;
    int count;
    bool empty;
    elements* firstElement; //the problem is in this line*********************
};
typedef struct myStack myStack;

void initStack(myStack *s, int size);
void cleanStack(myStack *s);


bool isEmpty(myStack *s);
bool isFull(myStack *s);

#endif
```

But when I am trying to compile it it gives me this error:

1. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'.
2. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

again the error points to this line of code:

```
elements* firstElement;
```

How do fix this?

Comment: Statements like `typedef struct elements elements;` are not necessary in C++.

Comment: Did you try `struct elements* firstElement;`

Comment: Declare all stack operations, including `push` and `pop`, in "stack.h", where they belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linkedList.h includes stack.h and stack.h includes linkedlists.h....you cannot do that. Then, your `#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H`/`#define _LINKEDLIST_H` makes elements not be defined in the end...

You need to remove circular dependency by using forward declaration, as below.

Change linkedlist.h by:

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H
#define _LINKEDLIST_H
//#include "stack.h"
struct myStack;

struct elements{
    int element;
    elements* pNext;
};
typedef struct elements elements;


void push(myStack *s, int element);  // insert element to top of the stack
int pop(myStack *s); //remove element from top of the stack

#endif
```

You can also create a third file with all the functions definitions, there's actually many ways to fix that.

Comment: i need a solution that doesn't uses forward declaration or third file.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't fix the problem without one of those. Except if, as proposed by moldbnilo, you move push and pop to stack.h

Answer (score 0):

If you use the C preprocessor to process a file that has the lines:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include "linkedList.h"
```

You'll see why `#include`ing "stack.h" from "linkedList.h" and vice-versa to get the definitions is troublesome.

I tried

```
cpp test.cc
```

The contents of test.cc:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include "linkedList.h"
```

This is what I get:

```
# 1 "test.cc"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.cc"
# 1 "stack.h" 1


# 1 "linkedList.h" 1


# 1 "stack.h" 1
# 4 "linkedList.h" 2

struct elements{
    int element;
    elements* pNext;
};
typedef struct elements elements;


void push(myStack *s, int element);
int pop(myStack *s);
# 4 "stack.h" 2

struct myStack{
    int maxSize;
    int count;
    bool empty;
    elements* firstElement;
};
typedef struct myStack myStack;

void initStack(myStack *s, int size);
void cleanStack(myStack *s);


bool isEmpty(myStack *s);
bool isFull(myStack *s);
# 2 "test.cc" 2
```

As you can see from the output of the preprocessor, `myStack` is not declared before the line:

```
void push(myStack *s, int element);
```

That explains why the compiler will report an error if you try to compile `test.cc`.

You will get different output if you switch the lines in `test.cc`. That will result in `element` being used before its declaration is available.

The way around that problem:

1. Don't `#include` "stack.h" in "linkedList.h" or "linkedList.h" in "stack.h"
2. Use forward declarations in both files to use the type.

The updated files:

linkedList.h:

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H
#define _LINKEDLIST_H

struct elements{
    int element;
    elements* pNext;
};
typedef struct elements elements;

struct myStack; // Use forward declaration of myStack.
void push(myStack *s, int element);  // insert element to top of the stack
int pop(myStack *s); //remove element from top of the stack

#endif
```

stack.h:

```
#ifndef _MYSTACK_H
#define _MYSTACK_H

struct elements; // Use forward declaration of elements.
struct myStack{
    int maxSize;
    int count;
    bool empty;
    elements* firstElement;
};
typedef struct myStack myStack;

void initStack(myStack *s, int size);
void cleanStack(myStack *s);


bool isEmpty(myStack *s);
bool isFull(myStack *s);

#endif
```

**Update, in response to comment from OP**

You can `#include` "stack.h" in "linkedList.h" after the definition of `elements` and make sure that you `#include` "linkedList.h" only in a compilation unit. If you `#include` just "stack.h" or `#include` "stack.h" before `#include`ing "linkedList.h", you will run into compiler errors.

Here are the updated files without forward declarations that work fine.

stack.h:

```
#ifndef _MYSTACK_H
#define _MYSTACK_H

struct myStack{
    int maxSize;
    int count;
    bool empty;
    elements* firstElement;
};
typedef struct myStack myStack;

void initStack(myStack *s, int size);
void cleanStack(myStack *s);


bool isEmpty(myStack *s);
bool isFull(myStack *s);

#endif
```

linkedList.h:

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H
#define _LINKEDLIST_H

struct elements{
    int element;
    elements* pNext;
};
typedef struct elements elements;

                   // myStack can see the definition of elements
#include "stack.h" // Now myStack available for use

void push(myStack *s, int element);  // insert element to top of the stack
int pop(myStack *s); //remove element from top of the stack

#endif
```

test.cc:

```
#include "linkedList.h"
```

However, if you use:

test.cc:

```
#include "stack.h"
```

you will run into compiler errors.

Comment: i need a solution that doesn't uses forward declaration.